# Fault Response Contains a String value where an Integer was Expected

Tags: c#, xml-rpc

Use this code to get a data query to a server with openerp, and consulted with the proxy below but returns me this error, I'm new at this.

```
[XmlRpcUrl("//IP:port/xmlrpc/common")]
public interface IOpenERPRPCClient
{
    [XmlRpcMethod("login")]
    int autenticar(string db_name, string user, string passwd);

    [XmlRpcMethod("execute")]
    int[] buscar(string db_name, int uid, string passwd, string obj, string action, object[] filtro);

    [XmlRpcMethod("execute")]
    int [] eliminar(string db_name, int uid, string passwd, string obj, string action, int[] ids);

    [XmlRpcMethod("execute")]

    object[] read_objeto(string db_name, int uid, string passwd, string obj, string action, int[] ids, string[] campos);


}

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   int uid = autenticar();
   IOpenERPRPCClient proxy_clientes =  IOpenERPRPCClient)XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IOpenERPRPCClient>();
   IXmlRpcProxy cliente_rpc = (IXmlRpcProxy)proxy_clientes;
   cliente_rpc.Url = "//IP:port/xmlrpc/object";

   object[] filtro = { "'Active','=','True'" };

   proxy_clientes.buscar("sgsoft", uid, "openerp", "res.partner","search",filtro);
   }
```

ERROR: An unhandled exception of type 'CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcTypeMismatchException' occurred in CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll

Additional information: fault response contains string value where integer expected [fault response : struct mapped to type Fault : member faultCode mapped to type Int32]

Comment: I'm only guessing. XML-RPC is not very popular. The message suggests that the problem is that the server is receiving your request, but returning a fault as a response. The fault response seems to have a string in the `faultCode` field, but your XML/RPC on .NET is expecting an integer there. I suggest you use Fiddler or something like it to look at the network and see what's being returned.

Answer (score 2):

OpenErp incorrectly returns faultCode as string message, it should be integer.

All you can do if you want to continue to use XmlRpc.NET is to download 3.0.0.270 beta version from [here](http://xml-rpc.net/download.html), that case is handled better in build 238. But be sure to set AllowStringFaultCode on your XmlRpcProxy:

```
clientProxy.NonStandard = XmlRpcNonStandard.AllowStringFaultCode;
```